# pandas plot replace xticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am plotting grouped panda data frame

```
score = pd.DataFrame()
score['Score'] = svm_score
score['Wafer_Slot'] = desc.Wafer_Slot[test_index].tolist()

gscore = score.groupby('Wafer_Slot')
score_plot = [score for ws, score in gscore]

ax = gscore.boxplot(subplots=False)
ax.set_xticklabels(range(52)) # does not work
plt.xlabel('Wafer Slot')
plt.show()
```

It is working well but the `x` axis is impossible to read as there are numerous numbers overlapping. I would like the `x` axis be a counter of the boxplot.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `boxplot` method doesn't return the axes object like the `plot` method of DataFrames and Series. Try this:

```
gscore.boxplot(subplots=False)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticklabels(range(52))
```

The `boxplot` method returns a `dict` or `OrderedDict` of `dicts` of line objects by the look of it.

Comment: `ax = plt.get_gca() AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_gca'`

Comment: Oops, it's just `gca` as in "get current axis". Answer edited.